# apache basic_authentication exception

Tags: apache, http, apache2, basic-authentication

I want to put the a server under apache_basic authentication, 
I added HTTP auth to the root of the server using this

```
<Location />
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Authentication"
   AuthBasicProvider file
   AuthUserFile /etc/authdb
   Require valid-user
</Location>
```

now this works fine, and it authenticate everyone in.

now I have uploadify which is flash, and used to upload images to the server. So as this is flash, the requests sent to the server get 401 errors, and I want to do the authentication expect the uploadify URLs.

I added more configs to the httpd.conf which is this

```
<Location */UploadifyForm/*>
   AuthType None
   Require all granted
</Location>
```

but this doesnt work, any one knows a solution for this please ?

Answer (score 1):

If *UploadifyForm* is under the root of your server these two directives should do the trick:

```
<Location "/">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Authentication"
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile /etc/authdb
    Require valid-user
</Location>
<Location "/UploadifyForm">
    AuthType None
    Require all granted
</Location>
```

Note that of your resources are on a filesystem, it is better to use `Directory` directives instead of `Location` ones. You can find more info in the [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html).